# How to get the error in Primefaces ajaxStatus onError()?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to implement

```
<p:ajaxStatus onerror="..." />
```

When an ajax error happens (I don't mean server side exceptions) and onerror is triggered, is it possible to know the specific error message that occurred?

Comment: I put a breakpoint inside the onerror javascript call. Looking through the arguments objects passed in, but still not finding an error message.

Comment: The JS console displays the error message. Wish I knew where it got it from.

Answer (score 0):

The `onerror` attribute can provide details through `arguments`:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onerror="myMethod(arguments)" />
```

and in javascript :

```
myMethod(arguments) {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

`arguments` is an object where you can find some useful error description.